# Not adding user while ending registration

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have small registration on Spring Boot and after that, the server (in idea) needs to add this person to a web page. Still, It gives me

```
"Whitelabel Error Page" and in console " Resolved
[org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException:
Request method 'POST' not supported]".
```

Can I fix that?

#### Here down is my code:

---

*Controller*

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class PagesController {
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    @Autowired
    public PagesController(UserDAO userDAO){
        this.userDAO = userDAO;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String index(){
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/list")
    public String list(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("USERS", userDAO.returnUsersList());

        return "list";
    }

    @GetMapping("/page/ID={id}")
    public String findById(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("USER", userDAO.showById(id));

        return "page";
    }

    @GetMapping("/registration")
    public String reg(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("USER", new User());

        return "reg";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String createUser(@ModelAttribute("createUser") User user){
        userDAO.save(user);

        return "redirect:/list";
    }
}
```

*DAO class*

```
@Component
public class UserDAO{
    private static int USER_ID;
    private List<User> users;

    {
        users = new ArrayList<>();

        users.add(new User(++USER_ID, "Georgy", "Ladidze"));
        users.add(new User(++USER_ID, "Mikley", "Smith"));
        users.add(new User(++USER_ID, "Mikley", "Jackson"));
        users.add(new User(++USER_ID, "Snoop", "Dog"));
    }

    public List<User> returnUsersList(){
        return users;
    }

    public User showById(int id){
        return users.stream().filter(user -> user.getId() == id).findAny().orElse(null);
    }

    public void save(User user){
        user.setId(++USER_ID);
        
        users.add(user);
    }
}
```

*Thymeleaf*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>REGISTRATION</title>
</head>
<body>

<form th:method="POST" th:action="@{/list}" th:object="${USER}">
    <label for="name">Enter your name: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" id="name"> <br>

    <label for="surname">Enter your SurName: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{surname}" id="surname"> <br>

    <input type="submit" value="REGISTER"/>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are doing a POST to /list; in the controller /list has a GetMapping, so spring is waiting for a GET

Comment: So I need to change POST to GET?

Comment: as far as i can unserdant you want to make a post and then show the updated page. I'd make a simple PostMapping where I do my DB operation and then I reload the updated page without doing any redirect

Comment: You need to call the correct method "/list" isn't for creating users. it's for listing users as the name suggests

Comment: "/list" is a page where is all USERS, and after REGISTRATION, the code needs to add this user in "/list", but it's not working.

Comment: @Kukushaa It's worked in Rest api if you have same endpoints for `POST` and `GET` but not working in `Spring MVC` because it's create ambiguity. You have to put `/lists` endpoint for `GET` and `/list` endpoint for `POST`.

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej Sorry but I don't get it :((

Comment: @Kukushaa I told you if you are working with Spring Boot, It is good to use same endpoint for POST and GET. But it is not possible in Spring MVC because if you declare same endpoint for POST and GET in Spring MVC then it will create a ambiguity.